# Where is the SQLite database created by my C# dotnet code ? (on a Mac)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I have a CS project that creates an SQLite database with this line :

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=my_database.db")
```

I'd like to inspect this database, using something like the `sqlite` command line tool.

But I don't know where the `my_database` exists.
If I search my system for a file of that name I don't find it.

**How can I determine where `my_database` is located on my file system?**

**Or, what command can I use to connect to `my_database` using `sqlite`?**

(I'm on a Mac)

Comment: Is there a command on a Mac to search your entire filesystem for a file with a given name?

Comment: I should have made that clear. There is no my_database.db on my entire system.

Comment: There is a similarly named .pdb file under both my obj and bin folders. It says it is encrypted if I try to open those.

Comment: `pdb` is a .NET thing - it isn't the database.